# Django / FactoryBoy - Overriding lazy_attributes

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I'm working on a Django project for which I've created the following factory:

```
class PurchaseFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = 'core.Purchase'

    amount = decimal.Decimal(random.randrange(100, 100000) / 100)
    ( .... )
    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)

    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def date(self):
        if not self.date:
            return timezone.now()
        else:
            return self.date
```

For which I'm running the following test:

```
class TestGetBalanceForPeriod(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.user: User = UserFactory()
        self.purchase_1: Purchase = PurchaseFactory(
            user=self.user, date=timezone.datetime(2019, 11, 1), amount=10
        )

    def test_test_setup(self) -> None:
        self.assertEqual(self.purchase_1.date, timezone.datetime(2019, 11, 1))
```

As you can see I've overridden the `date` field on the PurchaseFactory with an `lazy_attribute`. However, in this specific test I'm attempting to set the date myself.
I imagined factoryboy would override all values with the values provided by the users, but the test fails with the following error:

```
AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 22, 16, 15, 56, 311882, tzinfo=<UTC>) != datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0)
```

The first date is the results of the `timezone.now()` call and not the date that I provided as an input. So far I've been able to override all values on the many factories in our project without problems - but I'm unable to solve this problem.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**edit**

As requested I've included the code for the `Purchase` model below:

```
class Purchase(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)
    ( .... )
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='purchases',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question in general, for this case you could use [freeze gun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) and keep `timezone.now()`

Comment: Can you show the definition of the `date` field in your `Purchase` model?

Comment: @Xelnor - Thanks for your reply, I've included the code at the bottom of my post!
@mfrackowiak - Thanks for the suggestion! `freeze_gun` would indeed help solve my problem. But as I need these multiple objects with multiple dates for some of my tests that would make the code a bit more verbose than I initially thought necessary.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted an answer; as I thought, the issue comes from `auto_now_add=True` / `auto_now=True` — a frequent surprise for FactoryBoy users, I guess I should add a mention of that common pitfall in the docs ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue comes from using `auto_now_add=True` in your Django model definition: Django will [override any provided value for `date`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1337-L1340) in that case, using the value from `timezone.now()`.

In order to opt out of that behaviour, use `date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable=False)` (or `default=lambda: timezone.now()`, easier to understand): it will default to using `timezone.now()`, but enables you to provide a custom value.

*NB: Setting `editable=False` keeps the default Django behaviour of preventing users from editing the field, which is often implied by automatically setting the value at insertion time.*

By the way, you don't need to check for `if not self.date` in your `@lazy_attribute` definition, FactoryBoy will use the provided value automatically.
This allows you to use this shorter description:

```
class PurchaseFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    ...
    date = factory.LazyFunction(timezone.now)
```

Comment: That solved is, thanks for the assist! (And your hard work on the factoryboy package, it has really helped our team)